# What should I use instead of 'lifetime' in this FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this FQL to access the profiles of people who liked my page. I entered my pageID near 'pageid'.

```
        SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=pageid AND 
              metric='page_fans' AND period=period('lifetime')
```

I am getting the following error

```
            {
               "error": {
               "message": "You must specify a bounded date range using unix time stamps as constant values.", 
               "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
               "code": 604
               }
           }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=pageid AND 
          metric='page_fans' AND period = 0
```

`period = 0` means that you are collecting lifetime metrics. If you want to collect metrics with shorter periods, you also have to use `end_time` in your query.

Comment: As it said in docs `Note: Each metric may not have all periods available`. Maybe your metric has no `lifetime` period available? Try `... and period =  2592000 and end_date = 1387497600` for metrics for last month.

Comment: Didn't get any data. I have 2 likes for the page I am querying

Comment: Do you have `read_insights permissions for all apps, Pages and domains owned by the current session user` ?

Comment: I am the admin of the page I am querying. How can I get those permissions?

Comment: Do you call your FQL from some application or website? If yes, this application or website should ask for this permission.

Comment: I am executing this from the Graph API explorer tool.

Comment: Benny, couple things to check: 1 - Insights has not been available for  pages with less than 30 page likes. 2 - Your end_date must be bounded with end_date > [unix_timestamp] AND end_date < [unix_timestamp]